# How can I pass a parameter to a function which isn't declared yet?

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing

Here is my code:

```
class myclass{

    public function index(){
        $words  = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];
        $result = sizeof($words);
        $condition = in_array($word, $words) || strlen($word) <= 3;
        $res = $this->investigate_words( $words, $result, $condition )
    }

    public function investigate_words($words, $result, $condition)
    {
        foreach($words as $word){
            if($condition){
                $result--;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Please focus on this line:

```
$condition = in_array($word, $words) || strlen($word) <= 3;
```

In this line, `$word` isn't declared yet. It should be the value in the loop which exists into `investigate_words()` function. Anyway, is there any solution how can I handle that?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? What should `investigate_words` do logically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Closure` in this case. The condition argument can be a callable like.

```
class myclass{

    public function index(){
        $words  = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];
        $result = sizeof($words);
        $res = $this->investigate_words( $words, $result, function($word){
            return strlen($word) <= 3;// || in_array($word, $words); You don't need this commented condition word's coming from array
        });
    }

    public function investigate_words($words, $result,callable $condition)
    {
        foreach($words as $word){
            if($condition($word)){
                $result--;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know it work or not *(I don't have access a computer to test it right now, I will do that later)*, but it seems correct. Thank you, upvote